# Resize disk usage of a Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-image

Every Docker container will be configured with 10 GB disk space, which is the default configuration of devicemapper in CentOS. So how can I configure every container newly created with more than 10 GB disk space in default? (The host server is installed with CentOS 6 and Docker 1.7.1)

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can. Use the `dm.basesize` attribute when starting the Docker daemon. For example:

```
docker daemon --storage-opt dm.basesize=50G ...
```

More info can be found in [the official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#options-per-storage-driver).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am sorry I forgot to post some settings in the question. The host server I use is installed with CentOS 6 and Docker-1.7.1. The command you mentioned about is not supported by Docker-1.7.1.

Answer (score 6):

1. *(optional)* If you have already downloaded any image via `docker pull` you need to clean them first - otherwise they won't be resized

   `docker rmi your_image_name`
2. Edit the storage config

   `vi /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage`

   There should be something like `DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS="..."`, change it to `DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS="... --storage-opt dm.basesize=100G"`
3. Restart the docker deamon

   `service docker restart`
4. Pull the image

   `docker pull your_image_name`
5. *(optional)* verification

   `docker run -i -t your_image_name /bin/bash`

   `df -h`

I was struggling with this a lot until I found out this link http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/03/daemon_option_basedevicesize/
turns out you have to remove/pull image after enlarging the basesize.

Answer (score 4):

For those who use Mac, here's an easier solution:
Click "Preference" from Docker icon in the status bar:

[image]

Then navigate to "Disk" tab, adjust the disk image size with the slider. Docker will take a moment to restart.

[image]

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

Above answers properly suggest we have to edit **dm.basesize** attribute of devicemapper,
but proposed solutions are out of date or simply does not work in my case.

First make sure your storage dirver is a devicemapper with:

```
docker info | grep "Storage Driver"
```

you can also check current max-size of container with: (default 10 gb)

```
docker info | grep "Base Device Size"
```

From [devicemapper documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/#manage-devicemapper)

1) edit dm.basesize in ***etc/docker/daemon.json*** file, or create new one if does not exist

```
{
  "storage-opts": [
    "dm.basesize=30G"
  ]
}
```

2) restart docker deamon

```
 sudo systemctl stop docker
 sudo systemctl start docker
```

3) run again command below to check if size changed

```
docker info | grep "Base Device Size"
```

**4) Its important to update current images so change is applied**

Comment: Can you please explain why I got downvoted? Only this solution worked for me only.